# Number of components Trucated SVD

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics, svd

One can reduce dimensionality by using truncated SVD. It performs linear dimensionality reduction by means of truncated singular value decomposition (SVD). However, one has to choose the number of components before decomposing.

```
n_comp = 25
tfidf_vec = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer="word", max_features=5000, ngram_range=(1,2))
svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=n_comp, algorithm='arpack')
tfidf_df = tfidf_vec.fit_transform(values)
df = svd.fit_transform(tfidf_df)
```

How to choose the number of components ?

Answer (score 13):

```
var_explained = svd.explained_variance_ratio_.sum()
```

the line above will help you decide if 25 components captures the variability in your data well enough.
Sometimes, `var_explained >= 0.9` or `var_explained >= 0.95` reduces how many variables you need going forward in your analysis.

Comment: What do you refer to with var_explained?

Comment: @mavavilj I don't understand your question so please take a look at documentation http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html

Comment: You write: "Sometimes, var_explained >= 0.9 or var_explained >= 0.95", what's var_explained? Is it `var_explaned`?

Comment: @mavavilj that's fixed now. Thank you.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xvfJXNGCQBM this lecture explains it well for PCA but it should be same logic with SVD.

Answer (score 1):

Academic answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Lindenstrauss_lemma

> In mathematics, the Johnson-Lindenstrauss lemma is a result concerning low-distortion embeddings of points from high-dimensional into low-dimensional Euclidean space. The lemma states that a small set of points in a high-dimensional space can be embedded into a space of much lower dimension in such a way that distances between the points are nearly preserved. The map used for the embedding is at least Lipschitz, and can even be taken to be an orthogonal projection.

Practical answer: try several dimensions to find the best value for your objective.

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/21489

Answer (score 1):

One way is to generate the number of components, explained variance by # of components, and the return when adding an additional number of components.

Here I have a Tfidf dataframe with a maximum of 5000 features. We will end with this sort of graph:

[image]

One can arbitrarily choose the number of components that satisfies his time-efficiency tradeoff.

Comment: How do you get that kind of chart?

Comment: What is Gain in the chart ?